# Run JavaScript after page load on WordPress using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, performance, pagespeed

I'm new to JS and I'm still trying to understand it all. So I've decided to give myself a few projects so I can learn the syntax.

I have a chat widget that loads when someone lands on my website. However, I'd like to only run this widget after the page has loaded to improve website performance.

How do I go about adjusting this script to run only after my WordPress web page has loaded?

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/...../default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

UPDATED: The widget developer suggested this.

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var w = window;
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
function l() {
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/...../default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
}
if (w.attachEvent) {
w.attachEvent('onload', l);
} else {
w.addEventListener('load', l, false);
}
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want it to load after the page has parsed add defer to the script tag

```html
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
```

otherwise to load it after everything else call it on window load :

```js
    window.onload = () => {

    var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
        (function(){
        var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s1.async=true;
        s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/...../default';
        s1.charset='UTF-8';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
        })();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

To run the javascript after the page has been loaded by the user.

Comment: The solution is the same as what noChillSunday did in their answer